# Is there any Feynman diagram for Baryon/Hyperon decay with missing energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, elementary-particles

I am reading the hyperon decays with missing energy [this paper tells for the prospects of baryon decays with missing energy](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs11467-017-0691-9.pdf)

I want to know some of the Feynman diagrams for hyperon decays. Can anyone suggests me some better links for documents of hyperon decays with missing energy with suitable decay examples. Thank you in advance

Comment: google "feynman diagrams with semileptonic decays"  . The neutrinos/antineutrinos will be the missing energy . follow the quark decays.

Comment: Thank you. I was checking for some rare decays Bi → Bf l+l− dilepton decays. e.g. sigma decays into protons with neutrino pairs.

Comment: In The above paper Table-7 (Type B).

Comment: If you cannot find it by googling you have to make it: write the quark content of the Σ and choose from the decays of the quarks what can give the combination of quarks for a proton plus a netrino antineutrino pair. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html